# How to retrieve a complex $_GET variables as a multi-dimensional array using codeigniter (not using querystring)

Tags: php, codeigniter, get

** I've googled for hours, and searched within stackoverflow. Found a few similar ones, but couldn't find a good answer yet.**

I'm thinking of rewriting my project using codeigniter.

I have a search.php with possible querystring:

```
search.php?o=1&kk=1&k=sales&kx=&w=4&l=New+York%2C+NY%2C+USA&i=222&i=229&i=225&i=238&i=237&i=203&el=3&eu=10&ei=on&d=5&d=4&d=9&d=6&at=&a=Any
```

Please note that $_GET['i'] & $_GET['d'] could be arrays.

I found some mentioned about

```
$this->url->uri_to_assoc();
```

Hoping I maybe able to retrieve $_GET values as

```
/i/222/i/229/i/225/i/238/i/237/i/203
```

or

```
/i/222/229/225/238/237/203
```

So I tested with 
controllers/show.php

```
class show extends CI_Controller
{
    function get()
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r ($this->uri->uri_to_assoc());
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

When I input in URL as the following,

```
http://localhost/index.php/show/get/i/0123/i/52/i/l2
```

The above code only returns the last input.

```
Array
(
    [i] => l2
)
```

My actual question is, in Codeigniter,
from URL above, is there a way to retrieve as an array as

```
Array
(
[i] => array ([0] => 0123, [1] => 52, [2] => 12)
)
```

or similar NOT using Querystring? (cos if I enable Querystring I can't use other Codeigniter helping features etc.)

So I could retrieve my original $_GET querystring as something like

```
Array
(
[d] => array ([0] => 123, [1] => 456),
[i] => array ([0] => 11, [1] => 99),
[dx] => 1,
[dy] => 'New+York'
)
```

in Codeigniter.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`?

Comment: Good point. I used $_GET in my old project hoping users can share their search results over Twitter etc :D. (I know it sounds silly.) I could have achieved the similar outcome by using url_shortener and assign it with $_POST stored in my db or alike. So I am considering to use $_POST which Codeigniter supports with form helpers for search query. (cos it seems that using $_POST for complex form inputs is far easier in Codeigniter)

Comment: And also note that Twitter has a character limit to their posts `:)`

Comment: exactly. so they could only post up to simpler queries. like search.php?i=1&d=9&a=any etc (not long queries like in my example)

Comment: Opps! I just remembered a very important reason why I chose $_GET over $_POST. It's got to be $_GET to let users to go back to their search results when they press 'backspace' button after viewing an item. ah~~~!!!

Comment: If you still want to use `CodeIgniter`, you can enable the `$_GET` array by following directions here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the raw PHP query string?

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

Then phase through it

```
$vars=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$vars=explode('&',$vars);
$d=array();
$i=array();
foreach($vars as $var)
{
   $split=explode('=',$var);
   if($split[0]=='d')
   {
       $d[]=$split[1];
   }
   elseif($split[0]=='i')
   {
       $i[]=$split[1];
   }
   else
   {
        $$split[0]=split[1];// note the double $$ signs
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this is something I already know. I used similar method for my old project already. My question was if there's a class or helper in Codeigniter to handle multi-dimensional $_GET.